# Approaches for OR Approaches of

Tags: prepositions

The title of my thesis is "Approaches of PID controller design with
applications and experimental validation"
(It explains various techniques for the design of controllers for various systems)

Is the correct usage "Approaches **of** PID controller design" or "Approaches **for** PID controller design"

Comment: You haven't given enough information here to know which preposition is the right one - each is used to convey a different meaning. Please [edit] your question to explain what your title is a summary of. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the [Tour]. :-)

Comment: @Chappo I have edited it

Comment: The answer is implicit in your edit: "various techniques **for** the design of controllers for various systems)". :-)

Comment: @Chappo It is different.  various techniques for the design of controllers OR various techniques of controller design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer "approaches to" (eg [approaches to learning](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/skills/self-evaluation/approaches.html) and [a new approach to PID controller design](http://smartgridcenter.tamu.edu/resume/pdf/cnf/NAPS_Pang.pdf)) but out of the two you suggested, I think "for" sounds better.

See also this question: ["Approach to" or "approach for"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35472/approach-to-or-approach-for)

Comment: I have given the full title. Is "to" still valid

Comment: I still think "approaches to PID design [..]" sounds the best. Compare https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1193756

Comment: +1 I agree that **to** seems the best preposition not only in this context but in combination with *approaches* in general. I would really only debate *of* and *for* if they were to be used with *methods*.